# Firefox crashes after nvidia and cuda update on 14.04

Tags: nvidia, firefox, cuda

I recently added CUDA to my laptop to be able to develop some parallel code I want. All went smooth and I managed to run the CUDA tests/samples with no problem. My computer seems to work fine apart from a big issue. Whenever I use Firefox to open a page it gets instantly very slow and in a matter of seconds my computer freezes. This happens even with pages like facebook and youtube which I expected to be working flawlessly.

I had nvidia 340.29 installed with cuda and then downgraded to 331 and now to 304.117 to see if the problem is fixed but no luck. Do you have anything to propose?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally did a clean install of ubuntu 14 and just changed to Chrome and everything seems to work ok now with only chrome getting a bit slow when flash is on a webpage.